# Making headings that depend upon later environments

Tags: macros, environments, labels

I want to typeset a test and a marking scheme. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcommand{\probName}{}%
\newcounter{probCounter}%
\setcounter{probCounter}{1}
\newcounter{partCounter}%

\newenvironment{prob}[1][]%
  {\setcounter{partCounter}{0}
   \renewcommand{\probName}{#1}%
   \section{{Problem \arabic{probCounter}}{: \probName}}%
  }{
   \stepcounter{probCounter}%
  }

\newcommand{\partName}{}%
\renewenvironment{part}[1][]%
  {\stepcounter{partCounter}%
   \renewcommand{\partName}{#1}%
   \subsection{{Part \Alph{partCounter}}{: \partName}}
  }{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{ques}[1][]{
    \ifthenelse{
        \equal{#1}{}
    }{}{
        \ifthenelse{
            \equal{#1}{1}
        }{
            \textbf{(#1 point)}
        }{
            \textbf{(#1 points)}
        }}
    }{}

\newenvironment{sol}[1][]{%
  \begin{trivlist}%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\empty%
    \item[]%
  \else%
    \item[\hskip\labelsep\relax #1]%
  \fi%
{\bf Solution: \newline}  }{%
  \mbox{}\penalty10000\hfill\ensuremath{\Box} % \hmcpset@endmark%
  \end{trivlist}%
}




\begin{document}


\begin{prob}[Prob 2 Title]
\begin{part}
\begin{ques}[10]
Q1
\end{ques}

\begin{sol}
Sol to Q1
\end{sol}
\end{part}

\begin{part}
\begin{ques}[20]
Q1
\end{ques}


\end{part}

\begin{part}
\begin{ques}[10]
Q1
\end{ques}

\begin{ques}[10]
Q2
\end{ques}

\end{part}

\end{prob}

\begin{prob}[Prob 2 Title]

\begin{ques}[20]
Q2 (parts are not the essential component in every problem, when it does not include the part, count it as 1)
\end{ques}

\begin{sol}
\begin{align}
step 1 \\
step 2 \\
e=mc^2
\end{align}
\end{sol}

\end{prob}


\end{document}
```

which shown as below:

[image]

What I want is a way of automatically generating the headings which give the number of parts and the number of points in each problem, and the number of points available in each part..

[image]

All of the headings `(X parts, Y points)` should be generated automatically using the information that is supplied later in the question.

So, if I add "Part D" (which worth 10 points) to Problem 1, then the first blue heading would be automatically updated to `(4 parts, 60 points)`.

A "ques" may not be nested inside a "part", just as in image since `Problem`2 does not have a "Part A". In such cases, the headings should still correctly reflect the number of parts and points. In this case,  `(1 part, 20 points)`.

Comment: You know that there are specialised classes designed to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New solution answering the question**

You want to build headings to your problems and their parts using information appearing later in the document. The obvious way to do this is using `\label` and `\ref` but as you want to do this behind the scenes the label names need to be generated dynamically.

**Dynamic labels for cross-referencing**

Below I have defined two commands `\dlabel` and `\dref` that function like `\label` and `\ref`, respectively, except that they use dynamic names for the labels, depending on the current value of a counter. The syntax is:

```
\dlabel{labelName}{counter}[value]
\dref{labelName}{counter}
```

Here "counter" is any ordinary latex counter and "value" is what is stored for cross-referencing (*anything* sensible can be stored here). If no value is supplied then the value of the label defaults to the value of `counter` (its `\arabic` version). The labels are stored in the aux file as `labelName-<counter value>`.

If you want to use the values returned by `\dref` you cannot just use `\dref`. Instead you need to use a special counter `\theextractedReference` (this is similar to how [pgfmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) uses `\pgfmathresult`). There is a third macro, `\Dref`, which has exactly the same syntax as `\dref`, that sets the `extractedReference` counter without printing the referenced value.

The dynamic labels use the [refcount package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) and some expansion tricks. They work both with and without [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and should be happy with any other package that plays with references (I have only checked hyperref).

**Your problem**

Once the dynamic labels are in place it is not so hard to do what you want. Most of the work you did already in your question. All that needs to be added are some commands at the end of your environments for adding dynamic labels, using `\dlabel`, and then at the start of the environments you need to build your headings using `\Dref`. There are some more comments in the code.

Here is the output of your MWE:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{refcount}

%% dynamic references based on counters
\makeatletter
%dynamic label: \dlabel{label name}{counter}[value]
\NewDocumentCommand\dlabel{mmo}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{\def\dlabelval{\value{#2}}}{\def\dlabelval{#3}}%
  \edef\mylabel{#1-\arabic{#2}}\edef\@currentlabel{\dlabelval}%
  \expandafter\label{\mylabel}%
}
% dynamic reference: \dref{label name}{counter}
\newcommand\dref[2]{
  \edef\myref{#1-\arabic{#2}}%
  \expandafter\ref{\myref}%
}
% dynamic reference: \Dref{label name}{counter}
%  - sets \theextractedReference equal to the reference value
\newcounter{extractedReference}
\newcommand\Dref[2]{%
  \edef\myref{#1-\arabic{#2}}%
  \expandafter\setcounterref{extractedReference}{\myref}%
}

%% problems
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcounter{problemNumber}% current problem number
\def\theproblemNumber{Problem~\arabic{problemNumber}}%
\newcounter{partNumber}% current part number
\def\thepartNumber{Part~\Alph{partNumber}}%
\newcounter{problemPoints}% points for problem: cumulative
\newcounter{partPoints}% points for part: cumulative

\newenvironment{problem}[1][]%
  {\stepcounter{problemNumber}% increment problem number
   \setcounter{problemPoints}{0}% reset points for problem
   \setcounter{partNumber}{0}% reset parts for problem
   % building the problem subheading: (# parts, # points)
   \Dref{problemParts}{problemNumber}% set \theextractedReference = #parts
   \let\problemHeading\relax% clear problem heading
   \ifnum\theextractedReference>0% add number of parts to heading
      \ifnum\theextractedReference=1%
        \def\problemHeading{1 part}%
      \else
        \xdef\problemHeading{\theextractedReference\space parts}%
      \fi
   \fi
   \Dref{problemPoints}{problemNumber}% set \theextractedReference = #points
   \ifnum\theextractedReference>0% add number of points to heading
      % add comma to heading as necessary
      \ifx\problemHeading\relax\relax\else\appto\problemHeading{, }\fi
      \ifnum\theextractedReference=1%
        \appto\problemHeading{1 point}%
      \else
        \xappto\problemHeading{\theextractedReference\space points}%
      \fi
   \fi
   \section{\theproblemNumber: #1% add header if not empty=\relax
            \ifx\problemHeading\relax\relax\else\space(\problemHeading)\fi}%
  }{% save number of parts and point for the problem
    \dlabel{problemParts}{problemNumber}[\arabic{partNumber}]
    \dlabel{problemPoints}{problemNumber}[\theproblemPoints]
  }

\renewenvironment{part}%
  {\stepcounter{partNumber}%
   \setcounter{partPoints}{0}
   \Dref{partPoints:\arabic{problemNumber}}{partNumber}% set \theextractedReference = #points %%% edited the partNumber counter
   \let\partHeading\relax% clear heading
   \ifnum\theextractedReference>0% add number of points to heading
      \ifnum\theextractedReference=1%
        \def\partHeading{1 point}%
      \else
        \def\partHeading{\theextractedReference\space points}%
      \fi
   \fi
   \subsection{\thepartNumber: % add header if not empty=\relax
               \ifx\partHeading\relax\relax\else Total \partHeading\fi}
   }{% save number of points for part
     \dlabel{partPoints:\arabic{problemNumber}}{partNumber}[\thepartPoints]}   %%% edited the partNumber counter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% from OP
\newenvironment{question}[1][]{
    \ifthenelse{
        \equal{#1}{}
    }{}{% increment point counters for parts and problems
        \addtocounter{partPoints}{#1}
        \addtocounter{problemPoints}{#1}
        \ifthenelse{
            \equal{#1}{1}
        }{
            \noindent\textbf{(#1 point)}
        }{
            \noindent\textbf{(#1 points)}
        }}
    }{}

\newenvironment{solution}[1][]{%
    \begin{trivlist}%
    \def\@tempa{#1}%
    \ifx\@tempa\empty%
      \item[]%
    \else%
      \item[\hskip\labelsep\relax #1]%
    \fi%
    \textbf{solution}: \newline
  }{%
    \mbox{}\penalty10000\hfill\ensuremath{\Box} % \hmcpset@endmark%
    \end{trivlist}%
  }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{problem}[First Title]
    \begin{part}
      \begin{question}[10]
      Q1
      \end{question}

      \begin{solution}
      Sol to Q1
      \end{solution}
    \end{part}

    \begin{part}
      \begin{question}[20]
      Q1
      \end{question}
    \end{part}

    \begin{part}
      \begin{question}[10]
      Q1
      \end{question}

      \begin{question}[10]
      Q2
      \end{question}
    \end{part}
  \end{problem}

  \begin{problem}[Second title]
    \begin{question}[20]
    Q2 (parts are not the essential component in every problem, when it
    does not include the part, count it as 1)
    \end{question}

    \begin{solution}
    \begin{align}
    step 1 \\
    step 2 \\
    e=mc^2
    \end{align}
    \end{solution}
  \end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Btw, the second problem contains no parts so I think that the only sensible heading here is to print the number of points available and say nothing about the number of parts. This is what my solution does. Alternatively, you could print the number of *questions* in the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. My main problem is not the red line...

I don't need the red line, instead...
what i need is the algorithm can automate to calculate how many parts under the problem, and how many marks the total....

Comment: @BaffinChu I won't have time to look at this until after work, but it might help if you added a clearer description, or an example, of what you want as this still isn't clear to me.

Comment: Thank you. Andrew, I've change the description. and my code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BaffinChu I have just updated the new macros so that they will work with hyperref

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and energy to this post. This teaches me so many things in so many levels.

But somehow I cannot parse the hacked code you just gave me, it gave "undefined control sequence"

Comment: I just checked and it works fine for me. What error are you getting? Have you cut and passed all of my code into a file and run into problems or have you spliced only part of it back into your example? If the latter then check that you have all of the packages that I have used.

Comment: The end of the log file shows:
! Undefined control sequence.
\rc@set ...safe@activestrue\endcsname \rc@refused 
                                                  {#4}\expandafter \rc@@set ...
l.123   \begin{problem}[First Title]
                                    
? 
! Emergency stop.
\rc@set ...safe@activestrue\endcsname \rc@refused 
                                                  {#4}\expandafter \rc@@set ...
l.123   \begin{problem}[First Title]
                                    
End of file on the terminal!

Comment: It looks like refcount is having a problem but I don't see this. Try deleting the aux file and latexing it again, might help, might not. Have a look in the log file as well and see what version of refcount you are using. I have `refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4`.

Comment: Also check to see that you same the same version of the `\WriteLabel` as posted above. I changed this and possibly there was an issue with the previous version, although again it worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25583/discussion-between-baffin-chu-and-andrew).

Comment: Hi, after messing up around (just adding problems) to it, and find out that next to Part X: "Total Y points" phase not always correct. I post a quick example below.

Comment: I posted on the chatroom we used yesterday

Comment: I found out that the counter of partNumber should distinguished under different problem, something like `partPoints:\arabic{problemNumber}` will do the trick.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. I will have only sporadic access to the internet for the next week.